# Hosting several "in development"-sites on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting

I've been trying to wrap my head around the best solution for hosting development sites for our company lately.
To be completely frank I'm new to AWS and it's architecture, so more then anything I just want to know if I should keep learning about it, or find another more suitable solution.

Right now we have a dedicated server which hosts our own website, our intranet, and a lot of websites we've developed for clients.

Our own web and the intranet isn't an issue, however I'm not quite sure about the websites we produced for our clients.
There are about 100 of them right now, these sites are only used pre-launch so our clients can populate the sites with content. As soon as the content is done we host the website somewhere else. And the site that is still on our developer server is no longer used at all, but we keep them there if the client wants a new template/function so we can show it there before sending it to production.

This means the development sites have almost zero traffic, with perhaps at most 5 or so people adding content to them at any given time (5 people for all 100 sites, not 5 per site).
These sites needs to be available at all times, and should always feel snappy.
These are not static sites, they all require a database connection.

Is AWS (ES2, or any other kind of instance, lightsail?) a valid solution for hosting these sites. Or should I just downgrade our current dedicated server to a VPS, and just worry about hosting our main site on AWS?

Comment: These question would gather more interest on serverfault
I suggest at first start with answering these question : what is the size of server you want to get, how much you would like to pay for it and why migrating it on to the cloud is beneficial for the business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put this in an answer because it's too long, but it's just advice.

If you move those sites to AWS you're likely to end up paying (significantly) more than you do now. You can use the [Simple Monthly Calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) to get an idea.

To clarify, AWS is cost-effective for certain workloads. It is cost effective because it can scale automatically when needed so you don't have to provision for peak traffic all the time. And because it's easy to work with, so it takes fewer people and you don't have to pay a big ops team. It is cost effective for small teams that want to run production workloads with little operational overhead, up to big teams that are not yet big enough to build their own cloud.

Your sites are development sites that just sit there and see very little activity. Which means those sites are probably under the threshold of cost effective.

You should clarify why you want to move. If the reason is that you want as close to 100% uptime as possible, then AWS is a good choice. But it will cost you, both in terms of bill paid to Amazon and price of learning to set up such infrastructure. If cost is a primary concern, you might want to think it over.

That said, if your requirements for the next year or more are predictable enough and you have someone who knows what they are doing in AWS, there are ways to lower the cost, so it might be worth it. But without further detail it's hard for anyone to give you a definitive answer.

However. You also asked if you should keep learning AWS. Yes. Yes, you should. If not AWS, one of the other major clouds. Cloud and serverless[1] are the future of much of this industry. For some that is very much the present. Up to you if you start with those dev sites or something else.

[1] "Serverless" is as misleading a name as NoSQL. It doesn't mean no servers.

Edit:
You can find a list of EC2 (Elastic Cloud Compute) instance types [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). That's CPU and RAM. Realistically, the cheapest instance is about $8 per month. You also need storage, which is called [EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/) (Elastic Block Store). There are multiple types of that too, you probably want GP2 (General Purpose SSD).

I assume you also have one or more databases behind those sites. You can either set up the database(s) on EC2 instance(s), or use [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/instance-types/) (Relational Database Service). Again, multiple choices there. You probably don't want Multi-AZ there for dev. In short, Multi-AZ means two RDS instances so that if one crashes the other one takes over, but it's also double the price. You also pay for storage there, too.

And, depending on how you set things up you might pay for traffic. You pay for traffic between zones, but if you put everything in the same zone traffic is free.

Storage and traffic are pretty cheap though.

This is only the most basic of the basics. As I said, it can get complicated. It's probably worth it, but if you don't know AWS you might end up paying more than you should. Take it slow and keep reading.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one question regarding the Calculator, spinning up a ES2 Instance with 100% uptime will have a base cost of $240 per month. And this is a pretty good indicator on the cost?

Seems like a pretty significant higher cost then using a simple VPS for hosting the development-sites.

However for our main web I'm looking into using a ES2 which will mainly be used to build a static version hosted on a S3. Seems to be both cheap and good performance.

Comment: There are many instance sizes, $240 is a t3.2xlarge, which means 8 CPU and 32 GB of RAM. That is probably a lot for a bunch of sites that just sit there and do nothing. I don't know anything about your sites, but a more realistic number might be around $25-$50. That's a wild guess as I have no information.

See the edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer bgdnlp! I'll keep reading and try it on a small scale before moving on. Cheers!